# Copying to clipboard fails

Tags: python, pandas, pyautogui

With the following code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    pyautogui.doubleClick(x=185, y=177)
    #prints next working day
    if a < b:
        todaystr = str(rs[0].date())
        pyautogui.typewrite(todaystr)
    else:
        nextbusinessday = str(rs[1].date())
        pyautogui.typewrite(nextbusinessday)
    pyautogui.click(x=281, y=246)
    pyautogui.typewrite('companynamehere')
    pyautogui.click(x=444, y=444)
    pyautogui.typewrite('Order no. '+ ordernumberoni[s] +' Department '+ordernumberoni[s][-3:])
    #click products
    pyautogui.click(x=136, y=150)
    #-----------TEST-----
if not filename.endswith('.xlsx'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    filename=filename[0:22]
    W = px.load_workbook(fullname)
    p = W(filename)
    d = {'SKU':[ p['B%s'%i].value for i in range (12,500)],'expdate':[ p['E%s'%i].value for i in range (12,500)], 'quantity':[ p['F%s'%i].value for i in range (12,500)]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    # truncate the SKUs
    df.loc[:, 'SKU'] = df.loc[:, 'SKU'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[7:12] if len(x) > 5 else x)
    from time import strftime
    import datetime
    ac=datetime.datetime.now()+ datetime.timedelta(days=150) 
    ad = ac.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    newdyn = df[(df['expdate'] > ad)]
    #copy to clipboard here
    df.to_clipboard(excel=True)
```

... the copying to clipboard seems to fail. Please note that I am trying to paste AFTER the program executed, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, just fired up a command prompt, loaded pandas, created dummy data frame, copy to clipboard, quit python and close terminal and my data persists. I think your if statement isn't fulfilling the condition.

Comment: @Datanovice can you elaborate on the if condition? I do seem to have files in my directory which are .xml and .xlsx files

Comment: are you sure? add a print statement if you aren't debugging as you go along to see if it works

Comment: @Datanovice print statement for df or what?

Comment: To see if the if statements condition is fulfilled